# Search bar by using LinQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Please could someone help me with this problem? I am trying to do a search form. everything works fine, but I type a username it shows me the result of the username that I typed, however, when I enter an ID or name it shows me the whole table

```js
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           

             var st = from i in db.Login1s
                      where i.ID.Contains(TxtID.Text) 
                      select new {ID = i.ID, Name = i.Name, Username = i.Username, Password = i.Password};
            GridView1.DataSource = st.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();

            var na = from n in db.Login1s
                     where n.Name.Contains(TxtName1.Text)
                     select new { ID = n.ID, Name = n.Name, Username = n.Username, Password = n.Password };
            GridView1.DataSource = na.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();

            var us = from u in db.Login1s
                     where u.Username.Contains(TxtUsername.Text)
                     select new { ID = u.ID, Name = u.Name, Username = u.Username, Password = u.Password };
            GridView1.DataSource = us.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();

            
        }
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively binding only the last datasource to your view. Combine your Linq statements in one by using `&&` in your `where` condition.

```
where i.ID.Contains(TxtID.Text) && i.Name.Contains(TxtName1.Text) …
```

Comment: I tried that but now it shows me the whole table for all of them, do you know why?

Comment: It only works when I enter the three options, I can't enter only one of them

Comment: I changed it to && instead of || and now it works fine, I can fill one of the fields of all of them, Thank you!